# How to extract all rows from a sheet that meet a criteria in a column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a sheet called Master, I want to extract all rows from that sheet that have the Value "Other Revenue" in Column E.

Been searching online for a way and cant seem to get it right

Comment: See [ask] a question with a [mcve]. Without information there is nothing for us to help you with. The closest I can get to an answer without any further details is for you to reasearch the `FILTER()` function.

Comment: Thank you! and sorry about my question asking skills. The Filter equation worked

Comment: @shadytadros - if you're curious (or at least for benefit of others, with / w/ Office 365) - there are very many alternatives (some longer, some even shorter).  see below.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j9gZEyim6DX6eZqGgM1w?e=jtfTg4) / screenshot(s) / comparison(s) refer:

*(Excel versions per table below)*

### **APPROACHES** *non-exhaustive sample*

**Method 1 - FILTER**

```
=FILTER(C3:F7,--(C3:C7=I3))
```

[Method 1 (Filter)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KcQ0.png)

*Office 365 - straightforward fn.*

---

**Method 2 - INDEX + SMALL/IF**

```
=INDEX(C3:F7,SMALL(IF(C3:C7=I7,ROW(C3:C7)-ROW(C3)+1,""),SEQUENCE(SUM(1*(C3:C7=I7)),1,1,1)),SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(C3:F7),1,1))
```

[Method 2 (INDEX + Ordered If)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmYpo.png)

*Office 365, however only due to presence of `SEQUENCE()` which can be exchanged with other functions that are compatible with Excel versions. E.g.  `ROW(A1:INDIRECT("A"&SUM(1*(C3:C7=I3)),1))`, `(ROW(C3:C6)-ROW(C3)+1)`*

---

**Method 3 - INDEX + SMALL/ROW**

```
=INDEX(C3:F7,SMALL(IF(C3:C7=I11,ROW(C3:C7)-ROW(C3)+1,""),ROW(A1:INDIRECT("A"&SUM(1*(C3:C7=I11)),1))),COLUMN(C3:F3)-COLUMN(C3)+1)
```

[M3 - Index + Small/Row alt. (non-365 vers.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMCyB.png)

*Any version of Excel*

*Variations naturally exist - e.g. `INDEX(C3:F7,LARGE((ROW(C3:C7)-ROW(C2))*(C3:C7=I11),ROW(A1:INDIRECT("A"&SUM(1*(C3:C7=I11)),1))),COLUMN(C3:F3)-COLUMN(C2))` also does the trick.*

---

**Method 4 - IF (w, /w SORT)**

```
=SORT(IF(C3:C7=I15,C3:F7,""),,-1)
```

*Office 365 - due to `SORT()`, however, per M2 (comment)-M3, blank rows can be avoided through dynamic ranges defined by ROW() (as alternative to `SEQUENCE()`, `SORT()`, or `FILTER()` for that matter*

[M4 - Simple IF (with/without Sort)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HqYN.png)

---

### **COMPARISONS**

[Pros / Cons with each approach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44cXz.png)

---

**References**

Inspired, in part, by `O. Cronquist (2021)` - see [here](https://www.get-digital-help.com/how-to-return-multiple-values-using-vlookup-in-excel/) for related/various other approaches with user-friendly clear screenshots to aide.

---